# How can I detect browser in web.config or in ARR (url rewrite)

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, arr

I am working on a third party tool, as its not https (secured), we use URL Rewrite (ARR) feature.

Now I also want to display an html if the browser used is not Chrome or IE11.

Is there any way where I can detect browser settings in web.config or in URL - Rewrite, please do let me know.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="BlockIE9" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="test.html" redirectType="Permanent" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="MSIE\+[0-10]\.0" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
    </rule>

    <rule name="TestURLRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5601/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks and Regards

cmr

Comment: most certainly not web.config. web.config is just a configuration file for your ASP.NET application. for ARR I also do not think so. you need to detect in your ASP.NET application itself by checking the Request.Browser property but remember, this is pretty bad practice these days to check for specific browser and versions.

Comment: Don't do browser sniffing, do feature detection.

Comment: Hi All, I have placed the code that I have tried. I am not able to redirect all the IE <10 pages to "test.html". Any idea where I am going wrong.

Comment: It just states as "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" , and does not redirect to "test.html"

Comment: Stupid mistake, negate = ture, means if it does not match the pattern. Removed that and all is well :)